# Banking system circular reference

Tags: python, flask

I am making a program for a bank, using flask. For some reason, whenever the client adds paid money, it gives him the ValueError: Circular Reference Detected. How can I fix this? I have tried using functions, and also tried using a different type of database.
                                                   
My code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, abort
from forms import AddItemForm, EditItemForm, AddPaidMoneyForm
import datetime
from replit import db
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "my secret key isn't secret when posted on stack overflow ¯\_(ツ)_/¯"

def floatToMoney(value):
  
   return f"{float(value):.2f}"

def reset():
  db['itemList'] = []
  db['paid'] = 0
reset()

itemList = db['itemList']
paid = db['paid']



@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
  total=0
  for item in db['itemList']:
    total+=float(item[1])
  owed = floatToMoney(float(total))
  
  return render_template('home.html', title = "Home page", items=itemList, total=floatToMoney(total), owed=floatToMoney(owed), paid=floatToMoney(db['paid']))

@app.route("/add-item", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def addItem():
  form = AddItemForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    
    print(form.price.data)
    print(form.title.data)
    
    currentDate = datetime.datetime.now()
    dateToDisplay = str(currentDate.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"))
    id = len(db['itemList']) + 1
  
    db['itemList'].append([str(form.title.data), floatToMoney(form.price.data), dateToDisplay, id])
    flash("Success! Item has been added.", 'success')
    return redirect(url_for("home"))
    
  return render_template('add_item.html', title = "Add Item", form=form)

@app.route("/log_entry/<int:id>")
def entryPage(id):
  return render_template('postPage.html', title="Post", post = itemList[id-1])

@app.route("/log_entry/<int:id>/delete")
def deleteEntry(id):
  db['itemList'].pop(id-1)
  for item in db['itemList']:
    if item[3] > id:
      item[3] -= 1
  flash("The list entry has been deleted successfully.", 'success')
  return redirect(url_for("home"))

@app.route("/log_entry/<int:id>/update", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def updateEntry(id):
  form = EditItemForm()
  entry = db['itemList'][id-1]
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    # print(form.price.data)
    # print(form.title.data)
    # print(form.date.data.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"))
    if form.title.data:
      entry[0] = form.title.data
    if form.price.data:
      entry[1] = form.price.data
    if form.date.data:
      entry[2] = form.date.data.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
    flash("Listing edited successfully!", "success")
    return redirect(url_for("home"))
  return render_template('edit_item.html', form=form, title="Update Log Entry")

@app.route('/add-paid-money', methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def addPaidMoney():
  form = AddPaidMoneyForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    db['paid']+=form.amount.data
    flash("Success!", 'success')
    return redirect(url_for('home'))
  return render_template('add_paid_money.html', title='Add Paid Money', form=form)

@app.route('/prices')
def prices():
  return render_template('prices.html', title='Prices')
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Stack overflow is asking for more details, but that's all the details I can give.

Comment: "Stack overflow is asking for more details, but that's all the details I can give." Please read [mre] and: 1) show code that someone else can **copy and paste, without changing anything**, to see the **exact problem directly** (hard-code as much data as possible, and remove any code that will not be used in order to cause the problem. Check whether the problem can be reproduced without creating a Flask app, whether it requires a specific template, etc. Keep in mind that you can call `render_template` directly without needing a server or routes.)

Comment: 2) Show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, formatted like multi-line code, that corresponds to that example. Make sure to **copy and paste, starting from the line that says** `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end.

Answer (score 0):

On the line where it says `db['paid']+form.amount.data`, it should be `db['paid']+float(form.amount.data)`